# How can i create an xor function in F# which can encrypt a byte array?

Tags: f#

How can i create an xor function in F# which can encrypt a byte array? There is this code here which i got from Github but it encrypts a string.

```
open System

let encrypt (word : string) = 
    let key = "KCQ"
    [ 0..(word.Length - 1) ]
    |> Seq.map (fun idx -> Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32 word.[idx] ^^^ Convert.ToInt32 key.[idx % key.Length]))
    |> String.Concat

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let encrypted = encrypt "IzzyDev"
    printfn "Encrypted: %s" encrypted
    let decrypted = encrypt encrypted
    printfn "Decrypted: %s" decrypted
    0
```

How can i modify this code so that it encrypts a byte array instead of a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your example to encrypt a byte array instead of string:

```ml
let toBytes (str : string) =
    System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)

let encrypt (bytes : byte[]) = 
    let key = toBytes "KCQ"
    [ 0..(bytes.Length - 1) ]
    |> Seq.map (fun idx -> bytes.[idx] ^^^ key.[idx % key.Length])
    |> Seq.toArray

let printBytes (bytes : byte[]) =
    printf "[| "
    for byte in bytes do
        printf "0x%02xuy " byte
    printfn "|]"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let unencrypted = toBytes "IzzyDev"
    printfn "Unencrypted:"
    printBytes unencrypted

    let encrypted = encrypt unencrypted
    printfn "Encrypted:"
    printBytes encrypted

    let decrypted = encrypt encrypted
    printfn "Decrypted:"
    printBytes decrypted

    0
```

Output:

```
Unencrypted:
[| 0x49uy 0x7auy 0x7auy 0x79uy 0x44uy 0x65uy 0x76uy |]
Encrypted:
[| 0x02uy 0x39uy 0x2buy 0x32uy 0x07uy 0x34uy 0x3duy |]
Decrypted:
[| 0x49uy 0x7auy 0x7auy 0x79uy 0x44uy 0x65uy 0x76uy |]
```

**Update**: I modified the code to display hex output.

Comment: let toBytes (str : string) =
    System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)

let encrypt (bytes : byte[]) = 
    let key = toBytes "KCQ"
    [ 0..(bytes.Length - 1) ]
    |> Seq.map (fun idx -> bytes.[idx] ^^^ key.[idx % key.Length])
    |> Seq.toArray

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let unencrypted = [|0xfcuy|]
    printfn "Unencrypted: %A" unencrypted
    let encrypted = encrypt unencrypted
    printfn "Encrypted: %A" encrypted
    let decrypted = encrypt encrypted
    printfn "Decrypted: %A" decrypted
    0

I tried to encrypt 0xfcuy but the output i got is not desired

Comment: I'm having trouble reading that. Is the only difference that you're using `[|0xfcuy|]` as the input? It seems to work fine for me when I try that.

Comment: The output is as follows when i encrypt 0xfcuy
Unencrypted: [|252uy|]
Encrypted: [|183uy|]
Decrypted: [|252uy|]

Comment: yes the input is [0xfcuy]. After decryption, i want the output to be [0xfcuy] and not [251uy]

Comment: Bytes are unsigned, so `0xfc` (hex) is the same as 252 (decimal). You can see that the decrypted result is the same as the unencrypted input.

Comment: okay, is there a way the code can be modified to ensure the output is in hex and not decimal?

Comment: I updated my answer to show hex output instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235908/discussion-between-dharmik-and-brianberns).